# Call PHP destructor explicitly in Proxy class?

Tags: php

I am writing a Proxy class in PHP.

To do so, I am using magic method to catch calls/get/set... to the proxied instance, and forward them to that instance.

However, I am unsure what to do in this situation:

```
class Proxy {

    // Proxied object
    private $instance;

    // ...

    function __destruct() {
        // unset($this->instance); ?
        // $this->instance->__destruct(); ?
        // nothing ?
    }

}
```

Should I (can I) call the destructor explicitly? Or should I just unset the object, knowing it won't really destroy it for sure (at least, immediately)?

Or should I just do nothing and wait for the garbage collector to destroy the instance?

Comment: You should wait for garbage collection unless you encounter serious memory issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do anything. It'll be taken care of by the garbage collector, probably at around the same time as the proxy.

Comment: What worries me is that maybe the proxied class will rely on getting destroyed at a specific moment, and by using a proxy I may introduce bugs. But I can't think of such a scenario...

Comment: @Matthieu: It won't. Destructors aren't guaranteed to be called at any particular time.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest that you do not free the instance class when the proxy dies.  I'm not sure how you do things in your codebase, but it is possible something will still hold a reference to your instance class. Safer to let GC take care of it.  Destructors are rarely useful in PHP.